# PHP multiple array - echoing the value of an array key using object

Tags: php, sql, arrays, oop

```
<?php

/* SC: Shop Category */
$SCStatement = "SELECT * FROM  shop_categories";
$SCQuery = mysql_query($SCStatement);

while($SCFetch = mysql_fetch_array($SCQuery)){
    $SCItems[] = array(
        'id' => $SCFetch['id'],
        'name' => $SCFetch['cat_name'],
        'desc' => $SCFetch['cat_description']
    );
}

$SCNumCols = 2;
$SCNumItems = count($SCItems);
$SCNumRows = ceil($SCNumItems / $SCNumCols);



function bindArrayToObject($array) {
    $return = new stdClass();
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $return->$k = bindArrayToObject($v);
        }
        else {
            $return->$k = preg_replace ('/<[^>]*>/', '', $v);
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

$newObject = bindArrayToObject($SCItems);

echo $newObject->name;

?>
```

The data i retrieve from the database is stored in $SCItems[] array. The problem is, when i echo the $newObject->name; nothing will appear. What to add this code to show the data using `$newObject->name;`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? you are binding the more than one row to an object later in result you will get only last row. you need array of objects. There are many logical errors

Comment: FYI, while fetching from the database, if you want to rename the columns to something else, you can directly query like this - `SELECT id, cat_name as name, cat_description as desc  FROM  shop_categories`

Answer (score 0):

Well, judging from this code, what you have is something like

```
$SCItems = Array(
 0 => Array(
  'id' => 1,
  'name' => 'name 1',
  'desc' => 'description 1'
  ),
 1 => Array(
  'id' => 2,
  'name' => 'name 2',
  'desc' => 'description 2'
  ),
);
```

And then from that your `bindArrayToObject` function trying to build the object

```
$newObject = new stdClass(); 
$newbject->0 = new stdClass();
$newbject->0->id = 1;
$newbject->0->name = 'name 1';
$newbject->0->desc = 'description 1';

$newbject->1 = new stdClass();
$newbject->1->id = 2;
$newbject->1->name = 'name 2';
$newbject->1->desc = 'description 2';
```

So, what you probably should do is loop over your '$SCItems' and then on each entry use `bindArrayToObject`

Such as

```
$SCObject = Array();
foreach($SCItems as $SCItem) {
 $SCObjects[] = bindArrayToObject($SCItem);
}
```

From there you should be able to access `$SCObjects[0]->name`, which would make much more sense to me

Comment: Thanks very much Jakob Nilsson-Ehle, your a hero